# VBA Excel Use a value as any part of an array

Tags: vba, excel

A really basic question I m afraid:

How do I use a value as any part of an array?

```
Sub test()

Dim x As Variant
x = Array(1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 1585)

    If InStr(Cells(1,1).Value, x) Then
        MsgBox "OK"
    End If

End Sub
```

In this code I am trying to check if the cell contains any value from the array

Comment: I don't want to complicate the question too much, but it's important to consider some other factors, namely the array size and the number of searches against the array per "session." If you are actually working with a 5 - 10 element array, then it won't make much of a difference. But, if you are loading a large array into memory, and performing a number of searches against it, you can expect performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Match and check whether a number is returned (which means the value is found in the array).

```
Sub test()

Dim x As Variant

x = Array(1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 1585)

If IsNumeric(Application.Match(Cells(1, 1).Value, x, 0)) Then
    MsgBox "OK"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if it doesn't have to be an array one could simply use a string as such:

```
Sub test()

Dim arrayString As String

  arrayString = "1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 1585"
  If InStr(1, arrayString, Cells(1, 1), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "OK"
  End If

End Sub
```